# Center align text and image horizontally where text length can vary

Tags: html, css, center-align

I have a `div` within which I have to place an icon and some text to the right of it, and arrange the entire thing such that both of them together remain center aligned (there is a small gap between the image and text). Problem is, the text length can vary. So if it is a short text like **Libya**, the entire element will huddle close to the center, while if it is a big text like **Bosnia and Herzigovina**, it will spread out (while still centered), the image inching close towards the left. I tried this:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='imagetext'>
    <img class='location-icon' src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/blue-location-icon-Location-Icon-Blue.png" />
    <span class='location-text'>
        Bosnia and Herzigovina
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the `CSS`:

```
.container {
  width: 260px;
  height: 298px;
  background: yellow;
}

.imagetext {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.location-icon {
  width: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  float: left;
}

.location-text {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}

body {
  background: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

This is the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/d8t9e0p6/3/. I am unable to center it even with `text-align` set to `center`. How do I achieve the correct center alignment?

Comment: `float:left` overrides center align.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated it https://jsfiddle.net/d8t9e0p6/4/

you had to put text-align center on the container,
and the imagetext container needed width auto and display inline-block;

```
.container {
  width: 260px;
  height: 298px;
  background: yellow;
  text-align:center;
}

.imagetext {
  width:auto;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, as JoostS said, get rid of your `float:left`s
Then, you will have a misaligned text string.  To fix this get rid of the `top:5px;` top on the .location_text and add `vertical-align:middle` to `.location-icon`

```css
.container {
  width: 260px;
  height: 298px;
  background: yellow;
}

.imagetext {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.location-icon {
  vertical-align:middle;
  width: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.location-text {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  background: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='imagetext'>
    <img class='location-icon' src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/blue-location-icon-Location-Icon-Blue.png" />
    <span class='location-text'>
        Bosnia and Herzigovina
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Updated to add** :

You can also drastically reduce your markup if you use a pseudo element:

```css
.container {
  width: 260px;
  height: 298px;
  background: yellow;
}

.imagetext {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.imagetext::before{
  display:inline-block;
  content:'';
  background-image:url(http://images.clipartpanda.com/blue-location-icon-Location-Icon-Blue.png);
  background-size:contain;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin-right:5px;
}

body {
  background: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='imagetext'>
    Bosnia and Herzigovina
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check out the update, assuming you have many of these, this should drastically reduce your markup.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `float:left` css statements.